# Cannot install Bioconductor's 'mygene' package on R 3.3.0

Tags: r, openssl, bioconductor, httr

I am on a computer with Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit), R 3.3.0 and [Bioconductor 3.3](https://www.bioconductor.org/install/#bioc-version).

When I try to install the Bioconductor package [mygene](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/mygene.html). I keep getting the error **'dereferencing pointer to incomplete type'** when R installs mygene's dependent package *openssl* and *httr*. Below is the full output from R.

Would anyone know how to solve this? Many thanks for the help in advance!

```
> biocLite('mygene')
BioC_mirror: https://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor 3.3 (BiocInstaller 1.22.2), R 3.3.0 (2016-05-03).
Installing package(s) ‘mygene’
also installing the dependencies ‘openssl’, ‘httr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/openssl_0.9.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1165388 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/httr_1.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 118882 bytes (116 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 116 KB

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.3/bioc/src/contrib/mygene_1.8.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 121213 bytes (118 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 118 KB

* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/opt/R-3.3.0/openssl-1.1.0/include  
Using PKG_LIBS=-L/opt/R-3.3.0/openssl-1.1.0/lib -lssl -lcrypto  
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/exeh/exe3/ccarlos/bin/R-3.3.0/include -DNDEBUG -I/opt/R-3.3.0/openssl-1.1.0/include   -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c aes.c -o aes.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/exeh/exe3/ccarlos/bin/R-3.3.0/include -DNDEBUG -I/opt/R-3.3.0/openssl-1.1.0/include   -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c base64.c -o base64.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/exeh/exe3/ccarlos/bin/R-3.3.0/include -DNDEBUG -I/opt/R-3.3.0/openssl-1.1.0/include   -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c bignum.c -o bignum.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/exeh/exe3/ccarlos/bin/R-3.3.0/include -DNDEBUG -I/opt/R-3.3.0/openssl-1.1.0/include   -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c cert.c -o cert.o
cert.c: In function ‘R_cert_info’:
cert.c:45:37: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
cert.c:49:50: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
cert.c:50:39: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
cert.c:50:62: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
cert.c:55:31: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
cert.c:62:31: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
make: *** [cert.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/exeh/exe3/ccarlos/bin/R-3.3.0/library/openssl’
ERROR: dependency ‘openssl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/exeh/exe3/ccarlos/bin/R-3.3.0/library/httr’
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘mygene’
* removing ‘/exeh/exe3/ccarlos/bin/R-3.3.0/library/mygene’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpgW4oJW/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package ‘mygene’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Use OpenSSL 1.0.2 until Bioconductor or Mygene ports to OpenSSL 1.1.0. In the meantime, you should file a bug report against Bioconductor or Mygene.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with Bioconductor or mygene. It's entirely to do with openssl. You can reproduce the problem just by trying to install openssl by itself. I recommend you file an issue with the openssl maintainer at https://github.com/jeroenooms/openssl/issues . Provide the full output of the attempt to install the openssl package, plus the output of the `sessionInfo()` function.

Comment: Note also that the `openssl`'s `SystemRequirements` line in its `DESCRIPTION` file (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openssl/index.html) says `OpenSSL >= 1.0.0` so make sure your version is recent enough with `openssl version`. If it is less than 1.0.0 try upgrading with `sudo apt-get upgrade`. On an Ubuntu 12.04 system I was looking at, `openssl version` reported version 1.0.1.